# Why the provided union of interfaces does not work as expected?

Tags: typescript

The last execution of the `test` function is causing errors:

```
type ToggleFunc = (a: string) => void;

type X = { toggle: ToggleFunc; handleClose: () => void };

interface ModalWithTriggerProps {
  trigger: ({ toggle }: { toggle: ToggleFunc }) => void;
  children: (options: X) => void;
}

interface ModalWithoutTriggerProps {
  trigger?: undefined;
  children: (options: { toggle?: undefined; handleClose: () => void }) => void;
}

type ModalPropsX = ModalWithTriggerProps | ModalWithoutTriggerProps;

function test (x: ModalPropsX) {
    if(x.trigger) {
        x.children({toggle: (a: string) => console.log(a), handleClose: () => {}});
    } else {
        x.children({handleClose: () => {}});
    }
}

// with the trigger and extra X typing it works
test({
    trigger: ({toggle}) => {console.log(toggle)},
    children: ({handleClose, toggle}: X) => { console.log( handleClose, toggle )},
});

// without trigger and without extra typing it works
test({
    children: ({handleClose, toggle}) => { console.log( handleClose, toggle )},
});


// it causes errors when with trigger and no extra (X) typing provided
test({
    trigger: ({toggle}) => {console.log(toggle)},
    children: ({handleClose, toggle}) => { console.log( handleClose, toggle )},
});
```

Errors:

```
Binding element 'handleClose' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Binding element 'toggle' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

Is there a way to fix it somehow?
[Typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKg9gcwQGwgMQK4DsDGUC8UAFAIYBcUAzsAE4CWWCAlAQHxQBucdAJgNwAoAaEhQAGgSgBvKMEQoIFeElSZcfKAAsSWHqgDCyOJUXEW+dl15QAvoIENgEGgDMSOaAFk4PEsgDqdMCaMPRIzgAKNHBglNICULJhCM4URDJyKtA2FBnyqEr56Nh4NuaW3PwJUDiadMg8NBBYaTHAdHBYlBRi5ZyVgjZCjs5uHlDevgFBmnAYwKF04TRRMXFS1bRLKTQA-BTYPBAuDBBVibX1jc2tYO2d3dKyRftQh8en-Fo6ehCGxqYiH0rDxbMCBgIhsJwF4fH5VrEJIRJn5AsFFssEXEAD4TOHTYJzBbJSLRWL2Fwle5YWQQajEAAeFBRyCxvXiiUSdBcRAZADotssWBtOaKoPzLg0mlh0pkFGlyFQtow+jgHnBUHyjAhSEwADTfXQGIwmNJ9KQ2MqCUU2KAQZAmDlixISupS5rpbRGv4mwHmy1Ma2coZQgD0oagAHcZrJNNBBTsoD87QzaCRxLJwAwEFAglG4DQANaUYR04DpaqJBOpYhSOWoMpsaRqroaiBaxBEesQJg2PWVmpu64tWte37-EwG7s5cTmmrqzXaoiG8e+qdFKC9-tWoThqMzIlJbbOJO6feE+YptOZsDZ3PAfNFktOagV0WS4dpKRj40A9dZRsLCeFtKDbDsdRXX9J2eLJNz7SFAyEAQ9zzHASAwEw4mcaIaCjOMaWjYIj2WU9QSwOArxodMiHZEQ7zAaIOF4M5S1fEVOWrGgv2nc0QLApduy3AcP2lL8fx9P8YIUQD2BkPjF07SCJOg7s4O3QMgA)

Answer (score 2):

I think *(think)* the problem is that you end up with a union of function types for `children`, which tends to be ugly.

You can solve it by using function overloads:

```typescript
function test (x: ModalWithTriggerProps): void;
function test (x: ModalWithoutTriggerProps): void;
function test (x: ModalWithTriggerProps | ModalWithoutTriggerProps): void {
    if(x.trigger) {
        x.children({toggle: (a: string) => console.log(a), handleClose: () => {}});
    } else {
        x.children({handleClose: () => {}});
    }
}
```

Your last call works just fine with that, inferring all the types:

```typescript
test({
    trigger: ({toggle}) => {console.log(toggle)},
    children: ({handleClose, toggle}) => { console.log( handleClose, toggle )},
});
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKg9gcwQGwgMQK4DsDGUC8UAFAIYBcUAzsAE4CWWCAlAQHxQBucdAJgNwAoAaEhQAGgSgBvKMEQoIFeElSZcfKAAsSWHqgDCyOJUXEW+dl15QAvoIENgEGgDMSOaAFk4PEsgDqdMCaMPRIzgAKNHBglNICULJhCM4URDJyKtA2FBnyqEr56Nh4NuaW3PwJUDiadMg8NBBYaTHAdHBYlBRi5ZyVgjZCjs5uHlDevgFBmnAYwKF04TRRMXFS1bRLKTQA-BTYPBAuDBBVibX1jc2tYO2d3dKyRftQh8en-Fo6ehCGxqYiH0rDxbMCBgIhgIXCV7lhZBBqMQAB4USZ+QLBRbLVaxJgUEGCGG4OEIpFEVETHwYmZzBbJSLRPEEiHEnCkpzkyno6ZYhkrJlxAA+VKmmNm82xO1xlHx-WsG0SiToLgpADotssWIqlbrkWrLg0mlh0pkFGlyFQtow+jgHnBUGqjAhSEwADTfXQGIwmNJ9KQ2MqCXU2KAQZAmeK6vUGupG5rpbRev4+wH+wNMYNKoZQgD0uagAHcZrJNNBNTsoD8w8jaCRxLJwAwEFAgkW4DQANaUYSI4DpaqJCupYhSM2oMpsaR2roOiBOxBEccQJg2N2Dmpx64tUdJ37-Ewe5c5cT+mr2x3Ooie-epo9FKCr9dBoT5ou0+ZJbbOKu6d-BOkazrRswGbVtgHbLse05fsdQuLdjTSKQ929AF7yyScLCeGdKDnBcXRvVDD2eLJHzXSFM1fAtCw7bte2oAddWHGgkOPf0cLwq9lyfDdDW3JCUJTNCSIUTD2BkDjL0XQihOI5cyOfTMgA)